# The macros in this project have been disabled

Tags: ms-word

When opening a Word document a macro should start and it did for a while.
But then I saved the document when the macro was activated and after that I get the error message:

```
The macros in this project have been disabled
```

when I open the document.

I have tried different security settings.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If error in your macro has blocked macros in project, it usually takes long time to search for a solution, as MS seems not approving wide usage of macros.

In Word : 
The solution about enabling macros in File -> Options -> Advanced is NOT enough.

Just go to:
Developer -> Protect -> Restrict Editing -> opens up right panel, push Stop Protecting button.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Word: Tools->Macro_>security and set to, say, medium. Alternatives include Trusted Locations and Self-Certified projects.

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon: in Developer, click on macro securiry, then enable all macros.
Restart Xcel

[image: Enable The macros in this project]